# lambda in start_pares in scrapy

Tags: scrapy, python-3.5

Could anyone tell me why the number of index variable in parse() is 10013 at all time?

```
class GetsourcesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'getSources'
allowed_domains = ['bizhi.feihuo.com']
base_url = 'http://bizhi.feihuo.com/wallpaper/share?rsid={index}/'

def start_requests(self):
    for index in range(10010, 10014):#11886
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url.format(index=index), callback=lambda response:self.parse(response,index))

def parse(self, response, index):
    video_label = response.xpath('//video')[0]
    item = DynamicdesktopItem()
    item['index'] = index # response.url[-6:-1]
    item['video'] = video_label.attrib['src']
    item['image'] = video_label.attrib['poster']
    yield item
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are giving the `index` variable reference and not a value, that's why you get the last value. You need to use `meta` object for the same. Please see the updated code below

```
class GetsourcesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getSources'
    allowed_domains = ['bizhi.feihuo.com']
    base_url = 'http://bizhi.feihuo.com/wallpaper/share?rsid={index}/'

    def start_requests(self):
        for index in range(10010, 10014):#11886
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url.format(index=index), callback=self.parse, meta = {'index': index})

    def parse(self, response):
        index = response.meta['index']
        video_label = response.xpath('//video')[0]
        item = DynamicdesktopItem()
        item['index'] = index # response.url[-6:-1]
        item['video'] = video_label.attrib['src']
        item['image'] = video_label.attrib['poster']
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `index` variable referred to from all lambdas is not copied to their local scope. It is rewritten on each next loop iteration.
Consider this snippet:

```
lambdas = []
for i in range(3):
    lambdas.append(lambda: print(i))
for fn in lambdas:
    fn()
```

this will print three 2's, the last value of `i`.

Instead of doing lambda callbacks you should utilize `meta=` keyword of a Request class:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-meta-special-keys